# Triangle inside of triangle

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

How can I produce a symbol like `\Subset` for `\triangle` (i.e., another triangle inside of `\triangle`)? See the below picture.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can superimpose a standard `\triangle` to a scaled down (but emboldened) one.

The parameters may need to be changed for different fonts. For instance the bold version of `\triangle` (like the smaller ones) is not equilateral in Computer Modern, so we need to scale differently in the horizontal and vertical directions. With other fonts this may not be the case.

I defined `\Triangle` with the same status of binary operation symbol as `\triangle` with `\mathbin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Triangle}{}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\Triangle@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Triangle@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\triangle}%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\triangle$\cr % the outer triangle
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{0.225\height}{% raise the inner triangle
      \scalebox{0.5}[0.6]{% different scaling in the x and y directions
        \boldmath$\m@th#1\triangle$%
      }%
    }%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% for showing the bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

$\triangle$ \fbox{$\triangle$}

$\Triangle$ \fbox{$\Triangle$}

$\Triangle\scriptstyle\Triangle\scriptscriptstyle\Triangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg the solution is what I was looking for. One issue: sometimes the center triangle is off-center, especially when I just write ```\Triangle``` in text. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @JacksonBodoviwitz As defined here, `\Triangle` can only be used in math mode.

Comment: I am using ```$\Triangle$``` in text, mean. Still, the triangle isn't centered.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stix2` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

\[
\whiteinwhitetriangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]